# apparmor="DENIED"

Tags: 14.04, latex, apparmor, texlive

I get loads of error messages like this in dmesg

```
[613107.890167] type=1400 audit(1402488663.041:108): apparmor="DENIED"
operation="exec"
profile="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer//sanitized_helper"
name="/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam" pid=9841
comm="mktexpk" requested_mask="x" denied_mask="x" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
```

It seems this is some problem with my LaTeX install. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Are you actually having issues? If you don't see any issues then you should really just leave it. If you *are* having problems with your LaTeX install *then* it is time to change something. It looks like you are using KDE and evince is trying to figure out what `mktexnam` is so it can give it a thumbnail. Just a wild guess after looking at the error message.

Comment: @Seth It seems to be all working, I am just at last trying to address all the errors I see.

Comment: Are you seeing any more errors? This doesn't exactly count as an "error".